# Exporting extremely large images; arrays generated via TensorProduct use 5 times as much RAM as expected?

Tags: export, performance-tuning

I am generating plots of the roots of certain classes of polynomials, in the spirit of the multicolored visuals on the Wiki page on [algebraic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number). I've thus far been able to make some extremely spectacular plots, such as this [3600 x 3600 image of the roots of the monic quadratics and cubics](http://www.flickr.com/photos/104348204@N05/11537579304/sizes/o/) (very low-res preview below)

[image]

and this [4600 x 4600 image of the roots of the cubics with lead coefficient 5](http://www.flickr.com/photos/104348204@N05/11558043636/sizes/o/) (low-res preview below)

[image]

and this [4600 x 4600 image of the roots of the cubics with lead coefficient 1 or 5](http://www.flickr.com/photos/104348204@N05/11577728955/sizes/o/) (low-res preview below).

[image]

I have been running into a RAM usage bottleneck during the `Export` step as I try to make more detailed visuals. To make the images, I essentially execute

```
Export["Imagename.PNG",Image[A]]
```

where $A$ is roughly a $4600\times 4600\times 3$ rank-3 array specifying the RGB color channels. I was having issues with the MathKernel swallowing many gigabytes of RAM and initially thought it was from the Image `Export` step, but it turns out it's due to the `TensorProduct` I used to generate $A$.

I've begun to observe that arrays generated via `TensorProduct` occupy 5 times as much RAM as I would naively expect. For example,

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
L = 2000;
a = RandomReal[{-10^6, 10^6}, {L, L}];
b = RandomReal[{-10^6, 10^6}, 3];
c = TensorProduct[a, b];
d = RandomReal[{-10^6, 10^6}, {L, L, 3}];
ByteCount[a]
ByteCount[b]
ByteCount[c]
ByteCount[d]
Quit[]
```

indicates that $c$ occupies 480 MB RAM, while $d$ occupies 96MB RAM. Choosing $L=4600$ shows that $c$ occupies 2.6 GB RAM, while $d$ occupies 500 MB RAM. Changing the ranges of `RandomReal` from $10^6$ to other numbers does not significantly alter the result. This is a bit unexpected, since both $c$ and $d$ are of the same dimension and same MachinePrecision entry type, and yet the manner of array generation seems to strongly impact the space it occupies in RAM.

Question: *Does anyone know why using `TensorProduct` to generate an array creates an array object which occupies 5 times the normal RAM amount as comparable arrays generated via other means?*

EDIT: After applying the packed array fixes, things work well. Here are links to the [two](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ushalt5feb19wal/Root%20Generator.nb) [notebooks](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wo4405fb73yrxgp/Root%20Visualizer.nb) that can be used to generate the images I used. *Root Generator* is used to compute and export the polynomial roots of one's choice to sparse matrix formats, and *Root Visualizer* imports the sparse matrices and exports the images. I use packed arrays in the RAM-intensive parts, and `Compile` the convolution kernel used to blur the image. If anyone sees any obvious improvements that could be made, I'd love to hear it.

## Update

Mathematica 10 has updated `TensorProduct` so that it returns packed arrays. So if you are running version 10 or higher, you should not run into this problem.

Comment: If you know [how to construct the bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), you may consider `BinaryWrite` your image.

Comment: @FrenzYDT.: I've also exported large images (up to 12000 x 3000 pixels), I was just looking for a way to do so that will bypass the transient RAM requirements.

Comment: @Silvia: I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: Nice images, btw

Comment: Beautiful. Do you mind to share your MMA code?

Comment: For example, `Export["123.png", Image@RandomReal[1, {4000, 4000, 3}]]` works fine for me (Mathematica 9.0.1, Linux). `MaxMemoryUsed` is less then 1 GB. Which version do you use?

Comment: Try working with ppm format, I find it exports much faster than png ( ppm is basically a raw dump with a header ). You can do better still memory-wise to BinaryWrite the data in small chunks.

Comment: Also - it may help to Clear/Remove other symbols from memory. Presumably you have some large code that generates the image data that is taking up a good bit of memory on its own.

Comment: @ybeltukov: I just realized that the real memory hog is not the Image export, but the TensorProduct used to generate $A$ in the first place. Apologies for this lack of investigation on my part, I'll rewrite my question to reflect this.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus It might be the case that your array is unpacked, which can lead to a huge memory consumption.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For unknown reasons, `TensorProduct` produces unpacked array (see *packed arrays* [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/4678)). You can use `Outer[Times, a, b]` instead:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
L = 2000;
a = RandomReal[{-10^6, 10^6}, {L, L}];
b = RandomReal[{-10^6, 10^6}, 3];
c = TensorProduct[a, b];
c2 = Outer[Times, a, b];
d = RandomReal[{-10^6, 10^6}, {L, L, 3}];
ByteCount /@ {a, b, c, c2, d} // Column
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {c, c2} // Column
Max@Abs[c - c2]
```

> ```
> 32000152
> 128
> 480800392
> 96000160
> 96000160
>
> False
> True
>
> 0.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Seems like something of an oversight in the `TensorProduct` code. Hopefully this might be fixed in the next version? @DumpsterDoofus it could be worth reporting this as a performance bug to improve the chances...

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Wolfram, hopefully it will be addressed.