# Visualizing how the zeros for this function change as its input parameter changes?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, visualization

I'm trying to explore how the zeros of a certain parameterized function change as its parameter changes.

```
dh[n_, k_, a_] := 
dh[n, k, a] = Sum[Binomial[k, j] dh[Floor[n/(m^(k - j))], j, m + 1], {m, a, n^(1/k)}, {j, 0, k - 1}]
dh[n_, 1, a_] := Floor[n] - a + 1
dh[n_, 0, a_] := 1
bn[ z_, a_] := bn[z, a] = Product[ (z - k), {k, 0, a - 1}]/a!
dd[n_, z_] := Sum[bn[z, a] dh[n, a, 2], {a, 0, Log[2, n]}]
```

The function I'm exploring here is dd[n_,z_].

n is the parameter I want to vary, and is a whole number $>= 1$.  The zeros are all values of z such that dd[n,z] = 0.  There should be $\log_2 n$ zeros for a given n.

Now, I already know that I can see the zeros for an isolated value of n as

```
zeros[n_] := List @@ NRoots[ dd[n, z] == 0, z][[All, 2]]
```

For example, if I try zeros[30], I get {-16.1801, -1.66598 - 0.772391 I, -1.66598 + 0.772391 I, -0.0879758}

I also know that I could visualize those zeros as

```
RootLocusPlot[1/dd[30, z], {k, 0, 1}]
```

But both of these techniques only address single values of n at a time.  What I really want is to see how the zeros change as n changes, particularly for different scales of ranges for n.

Does Mathematica have any tools to help me do that?

Comment: How about `pts=Table[(Point[{Re[#], Im[#]}])& /@ zeros[n], {n, 5, 30}]` and then plotting the points as in `Show[Graphics[pts], Frame -> True]` or some other graphics command? You could also use `Manipulate` instead of Table, above (with some minor modification).

Comment: Take a look at this answer [Factoring a two variable polynomial in a special way](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38602/factoring-a-two-variable-polynomial-in-a-special-way/38607#38607).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Peltio's idea:

```
colfunc = ColorData["AvocadoColors"];
pts = Table[{colfunc[n/30], Point[{Re[#], Im[#]}]} & /@ zeros[n], {n, 5, 30}];
Graphics[pts, Frame -> True]
```

The color function is meant to give you an idea of which n a root correspond to. Of course it is optional, without it it's just Peltio's code.

[image: roots]

The most beautiful visualization of roots I've seen on here is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39412/exporting-extremely-large-images-arrays-generated-via-tensorproduct-use-5-times).