# Table and memory efficiency

Tags: matrix, memory

Consider these two types of creating matrices:

```
Table[Table[i*j,{i,1,10}],{j,1,10}]

Table[i*j,{i,1,10},{j,1,10}]
```

I want to know if there is any difference between these two in terms of memory efficiency.

```
N@(ByteCount[Table[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}], {j, 1, 10}]]/ByteCount[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]])
```

If the size of the matrix is 10by10 both methods use the same amount of memory, for 100by100 the first method uses more memory, and for 1000by1000 case both use the same amount of memory.

1. Why aren't both method memory efficient equally?
2. Why the second method has advantage just over a limited range of matrix size?

The second part is comparing these two codes:

```
n = 100;
ByteCount[Table[i*j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]
(*250496*)
```

and

```
ByteCount[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}]]
(*80152*)
```

Why does setting the limits of the table by `n` make it less memory efficient?

I use *Mathematica* 9.

### Edit

If I make a table of matrices, there isn't significant difference in size between packed and unpacked arrays:

```
<< Developer`
id = IdentityMatrix[100];
a = Table[{id[[i]]}\[Transpose].{id[[i]]}, {i, 1, 100}];
b = ToPackedArray[Table[{id[[i]]}\[Transpose].{id[[i]]}, {i, 1, 100}]];
PackedArrayQ[a]
PackedArrayQ[b]
ByteCount[a]/(1.0*ByteCount[b])
```

Comment: Bracket missing in `Table[Table[i*j,{i,1,10},{j,1,10}]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Part 1:

It has to do with [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array). Packed arrays occupy around [1/3 to 1/4 the size of unpacked arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39412/exporting-extremely-large-images-arrays-generated-via-tensorproduct-use-5-times), giving the results you see. You can verify this as follows:

```
<< Developer`
PackedArrayQ[Table[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}], {j, 1, 10}]]
PackedArrayQ[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]]
PackedArrayQ[Table[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 100}], {j, 1, 100}]]
PackedArrayQ[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}]]
PackedArrayQ[Table[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 1000}], {j, 1, 1000}]]
PackedArrayQ[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 1000}]]
```

producing

```
False
False
False
True
True
True
```

Explanation: Mathematica tries to pack an array when the number of elements exceeds a certain threshold (250). In your nested `Table` of `Table` version for the 100-by-100 case, 100 is below this threshold, generating an unpacked array of unpacked arrays whose overall size (10000 elements) exceeds the packed array limit. In contrast, the single-`Table` version realizes that 10000 is over the threshold, and produces a single packed array.

Likewise, in the 10-by-10 case, both cases fall under the threshold, and in the 1000-by-1000 case, both exceed the threshold, so they both are equally efficient.

Incidentally, you can determine the threshold by the following:

```
PackedArrayQ[Table[i, {i, 249}]]
PackedArrayQ[Table[i, {i, 250}]]
```

which produces

```
False
True
```

This explains the behavior you see.

#### Part 2:

The first case doesn't pack your array:

```
n = 100;
PackedArrayQ[Table[i*j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]
PackedArrayQ[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}]]
(*False*)
(*True*)
```

I'm not sure why that's the case, though. Anyone know why? In any case, you can convert an array to a packed array using `ToPackedArray`:

```
PackedArrayQ[ToPackedArray@Table[i*j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]
(*True*)
```

#### Part 3 (addressing your Edit)

`IdentityMatrix` by default returns packed arrays. The product of two packed arrays is a packed array. As a result, `a` is an unpacked vector of packed matrices. Since the unpacked coarseness is at the top level, the size difference between the "unpacked" array `a` and the packed array `b` is very small.

You can confirm this by the following:

```
PackedArrayQ[a]
PackedArrayQ[a[[1]]] 
(*False*)
(*True*)
```

So in fact, you really are getting a factor of 3 size reduction from the packing, but it's not immediately apparent from a `ByteCount` comparison with the "unpacked" array.

Comment: If I use Developer`ToPackedArray[] for the second part, it won't be packed. Isn't this command supposed to do that?

Comment: @yashar: See my edit just now. In my case it does get packed. Could you share the code you used?

Comment: I was wrong, it gets packed. I just restarted MMA and did it again.

Comment: Is this always true that packed array are 1/4 of unpacked ones?

If I make a table of matrices, there isn't that much difference between packed ones and unpacked ones.

Comment: @yashar: I can't reproduce your result. `ByteCount[Table[i*j*k, {i, 100}, {j, 100}, {k, 100}]]
ByteCount[Table[Table[Table[i*j*k, {i, 100}], {j, 100}], {k, 100}]]` gives `8000160` and `25050496`. However, I was wrong about the packing ratio, it's more like 1/3 of the size, not 1/4.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the edited question. I added the code for making a table of matrices.

Comment: @yashar: I addressed your edit. In effect, you are comparing a packed array and an "almost entirely packed" array that is packed everywhere except at the top level, and thus aren't seeing much of a difference. However, the factor of 1/3 to 1/4 compression is still there.

Comment: Part 2. if you have a look at the `Trace` of both they are quite different. To fix this `With[{n = 100}, Table[i*j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]`