# How to generate this structure of a list without `While` and the like?

Tags: function-construction, coding-style

I need to create a list that holds, for given integer `d`, the elements
$1,\ldots,d,d+2,\ldots,2d,2d+3,\ldots,3d,3d+4,\ldots,d^2$ where $\ldots$ is just denoting increment by 1 until the next written value is reached (as usual).

My naive attempt is this:

```
ClearAll[list];
list[d_] := Module[{tmp = {}, n = 0}, While[(n + 1)*d <= d^2, AppendTo[tmp, Range[n*(d + 1) + 1, (n + 1)*d]]; n++]; Flatten@tmp];
```

which produces what I want, e.g.

```
list[3]
(* {1,2,3,5,6,9} *)
```

However, I would be very interested how (or maybe if) this can be achieved without using things like `While` and `For`. I guess there is a nice approach for this...

**Update**

Here are some timings for the current approaches on my machine:

[image]

At least for larger `d`, the second solution by @ciao scales best (although only marginally faster than the one by @gpap). Since ciao's approach is also faster than gpap's for small `d`, I decided to accept his solution. But all approaches are very nice, so it was a bit difficult to choose the "one" that will be accepted.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I definitely prefer this over my attempt. Didn't think about using this feature of `Table` :) So, yes, this would be an option (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems pretty quick...

```
Block[{base = ConstantArray[1, Binomial[# + 1, 2]]},
  base[[Accumulate@Range[#, 2, -1] + 1]] += Range[# - 1];
  Accumulate@base] &
```

and this seems faster...

```
Block[{r = Range[#, #^2, #]}, Join @@ Range[Subtract[r, Range[# - 1, 0, -1]], r]] &
```

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you're building a list with `While` or `For`, there's a good chance `Table` or `Array` can help. In this case, the solution with `Table` is quite simple: just use two iterators and make the bounds of the second dependent on the first iterator:

```
list[d_] := Join @@ Table[i*d + j, {i, 0, d}, {j, i + 1, d}]
```

The `Join @@` is used to flatten the array. `Flatten @` would also do, but I prefer the former when I know that I'm only flattening one level.

As you noted this is quite a bit slower than your own solution. If performance is a concern, you can use this slightly less readable form that combines `Table` with `Range` and appears to be about 10 to 20 times faster than your code:

```
list[d_] := Join @@ Table[Range[i*d + i + 1, (i + 1) d], {i, 0, d}]
```

Comment: It is syntax-wise a lot shorter than my approach, but the timings of this approach are pretty bad for large `d`, e.g. for `d=1000` it is 5 times slower than my approach whereas for `d=10000` it is already a factor of `8`. Do you know /Can you explain why the `Table` scales so poorly?

Comment: @Lukas I assume your `Range` is a fair bit faster. It should be easily possible to combine `Table` with `Range` though, I'll run some timings myself.

Comment: @Lukas See update.

Comment: Now it is very competitive to the one by gpap. I have added a plot with timings to my question :)

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
f[d_] := Join @@ MapThread[
   Range, 
   Transpose@Table[{(i - 1) d + i, i d}, {i, d}]
   ];
```

so

```
f[3]
{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9}
```

and it's pretty fast as well:

```
AbsoluteTiming[f[10000];]
{0.410494, Null}
```

same caveat about `Join@@` vs `Flatten@` as Martin Büttner by whose wise comment this can be simplified to merely:

```
f[d_] := Join @@ Range @@@ Table[{(i - 1) d + i, i d}, {i, d}]
```

Comment: This is a really nice one. About 1.5 orders of magnitude faster than my approach. Does this have to do with `PackedArray` or so? I do only have a brief idea about this, but have read it in varoius answers here where it makes a huge difference in timings...

Comment: exactly. I am not clear on when `Table` with two indices produces a packed array but [there is a relevant reference on this website](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70186/table-and-memory-efficiency/70187#70187)

Comment: Thanks alot for this reference! Very useful for this kind of things

Comment: `Range @ ## &` is the same thing as `Range` (but a bit slower due to the overhead of calling the function). Also you can void all the `MapThread` and `Transpose` shenanigans and also get much better readability by using `@@@` (`Apply` with level spec `{1}`), i.e. `Join @@ Range @@@ Table[{(i - 1) d + i, i d}, {i, d}]`. Interestingly, the latter optimisation doesn't actually seem to speed up the code any further.

Comment: lol, you are right - I was too focused on getting the indices right that I missed the mountain for the finger!

Answer (score 4):

different ... but slow :)

```
f1 = SparseArray[UpperTriangularize[Partition[Range[#^2], #]]][ "NonzeroValues"] &

f1 /@ {3, 4}
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9},
>   {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16}}

Also different but slower:

```
f2 = Flatten[UpperTriangularize[Partition[Range[#^2], #]] /. 0 -> (## &[])] &

f3 = Sort[SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i <= j :> (i - 1) # + j, {#, #}]["NonzeroValues"]] &;
f1 /@ {3, 4} == f2 /@ {3, 4} == f3 /@ {3, 4}
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

Another way without `Table`:

```
listN[d_]:= Join @@ NestList[d + Rest@# &, Range[d], d - 1]
```

It performs not so bad but slower than the fastest methods.

Answer (score 3):

This seems a different approach, exchanging Table by ConstantArray and Accumulate

```
sieve[d_] := 
Module[{u = ConstantArray[1, d (d + 1)/2], o = Range[2, d], index},
  index = 1 + Accumulate[Reverse[o]];
  u[[index]] = o;
  Accumulate[u]
]
```

However, it does not seem to perform better than the other algorithms in my notebook:

```
AbsoluteTiming[sieve[10000];]
{0.923706, Null}
```

The procedural approach using the index table is faster:

```
proc[d_] := Module[{u = Range[d (d + 1)/2], filling, index},
  filling = Accumulate[ u[[1 ;; d]] ];
  index = 1 + Accumulate[ Reverse[ u[[1 ;; d]] ] ];
  Do[ u[[index[[i]] ;; index[[i + 1]] - 1 ]] += filling[[i]], {i,Length[index] - 1} ];
  u
  ]

AbsoluteTiming[ proc[10000];]
{0.588404, Null}
```